# Disable resume download capability in nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to disable resume download in nginx server? I want to stop resume download capability in from URL `example.com/media/` but I have no idea how to do that. Also I've searched through internet but I couldn't find anything related to nginx. Is it a server config? Or I should do something else? This is my server config:

```
# sites-avalaible/default
server {
        listen  80;
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name     www.example.com example.com;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/example/ssl/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /var/www/example/ssl/ssl.key;
        location /static  {
                alias   /var/www/example/static;
                expires 7d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

        }
        location /media  {
                alias  /var/www/example/media;
                # limit download speed after 5mb download
                limit_rate_after 5m;
                limit_rate 120k;
                limit_req zone=lh burst=5 nodelay;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
}
```

Comment: You really should not disable it. That produces worse user experience(having to redownload the whole thing if the last byte is missing.) and it can cost you more because more bandwidth is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [max_ranges](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#max_ranges) parameter.

```
syntax: max_ranges number;
default:     —
context:    http, server, location
This directive appeared in version 1.1.2.
```

> Limits the maximum allowed number of ranges in byte-range requests.
>   Requests that exceed the limit are processed as if there were no byte
>   ranges specified. By default, the number of ranges is not limited. The
>   zero value disables the byte-range support completely.

Set `max_ranges` to `0` in whatever context you find appropriate.